# Prevent duplicate value in select fields

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to compare select fields below to prevent the user from submitting same fruit name.

For example

```
Field #1: Apple
Field #2: Apple 
Field #3: Banana
```

The code I have so far:

View

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
           <th>Product</th>
           <th>Quantity</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="body">
        <tr>
           <td>{!! Form::select('fruits[]', $products, null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}</td>
           <td>{!! Form::text('quantity[]', null, ['placeholder' => 'Insert Quantity', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>{!! Form::select('fruits[]', $products, null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}</td>
           <td>{!! Form::text('quantity[]', null, ['placeholder' => 'Insert Quantity', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>{!! Form::select('fruits[]', $products, null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}</td>
           <td>{!! Form::text('quantity[]', null, ['placeholder' => 'Insert Quantity', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Controller

```
$products = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange'];

$inputs = Input::all();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($inputs['fruits']); $i++) {

    if($inputs['fruits'][$i] == ????? ){ <-- Here is my problem

    return back();

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a temporary variable which stores your selected products?

```
$products = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange'];

$inputs = Input::all();

$selected_products = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($inputs['fruits']); $i++) {
    $product = $inputs['fruits'][$i];

    if (isset($selected_products[$product]))
        return back();

    $selected_products[$product] = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @MarcoFlorian! You saved my time :)